# Cannot override Linux defconfig for NXP i.MX8 linux-imx package in Yocto Kirkstone

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, nxp-microcontroller

I am using Yocto to produce a build for a SolidRun i.MX8 platform. For this I am using the official NXP Kirkstone release with the Linux kernel 5.15.

```
# Inialize NXP repositories
RUN .bin/repo init -u https://github.com/nxp-imx/imx-manifest.git -b imx-linux-kirkstone -m imx-5.15.71-2.2.0.xml
```

I have a bbappend in my own layer that I want to override the kernel defconfig with. No matter what I do, the original defconfig is never overridden.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
# Include kernel configuration fragment
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://defconfig \
            "

do_configure_append() {
    bbwarn "1.) Applying Sensonix Linux Kernel configuration fragment ..."
    cat ${WORKDIR}/defconfig >> ${B}/.config
}

KBUILD_DEFCONFIG_imx8mpsolidrun = ""
unset KBUILD_DEFCONFIG

do_copy_defconfig_append () {

    bbwarn "2.) Applying Sensonix Linux Kernel configuration fragment ..."

    #cp ${WORKDIR}/defconfig ${WORKDIR}/defconfig
    cp ${WORKDIR}/defconfig ${WORKDIR}/build/.config
}
```

How can I successfully override the linux-imx defconfig with NXP's official Yocto Kirkstone release?

Comment: Do you see your warn/log messages during build? I would expect them not to be executed due to the old override syntax. As the first step I'd rename do_copy_defconfig_append() to do_copy_defconfig:append() to match the updated syntax, and give it another go.

Comment: @skandigraun - thanks for the input. I did change to the new syntax and tried again. Unfortunately, it did not help. I can see that my 2 functions are being called because the bbwarn messages show up on the console. I've been able to do this type of thing with 'meta-atmel' and 'meta-nvidia' - so I'm a bit confused as to why meta-imx is different.